# How is obtaining the size of a Java array object O(1)?

Tags: java

I am just beginning to learn Java and heard that getting the size of an array is O(1). Why is it not O(n)?

Mustn't the java virtual machine count the number of items in the array?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, the number of items in the array is fixed when you create it.

Comment: Strictly speaking, it is fixed when you *create* it.

Comment: Thank you! Interestingly though, I googled around and realized that finding the length of a list in Python is also O(1), and the lengths of Python lists are not fixed upon creation.

Comment: @JohnHoffman - you are right.  There is no direct causal relationship between fixed sized arrays and `array.length` being `O(1)` ... in either direction.  The performance of `array.length` is determined by the implementation ... for every model of arrays that I've ever come across.  (Note - strings are not arrays ... and in some languages, it is impossible to determine the length of an arbitrary array.)

Answer (score 3):

> Mustn't the java virtual machine count the number of items in the array?

That is not necessary.  The JVM representation for an array has a special field that gives the length of the array instance, and a special bytecode for accessing it.  When it needs the length, the JVM uses these.

(It is also true that an array's length is fixed when the array has been created ... but that doesn't directly answer the question.  Hypothetically, the JVM *could* still count elements.  However, I find it hard to see how the JVM would decide where / when to stop counting elements.  How would it know when the bits it is looking at don't represent a valid value of the array base-type?)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned above, it's a special bytecode function:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_bytecode_instruction_listings

arraylength be      arrayref → length   get the length of an array